# (XAML) UserControl within a usercontrol, the listview have no scrollbar and display whole content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I wanna put two usercontrols into another usercontrol. Here is the User control that i wanna put in.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.MainModule.Views.ReportView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Project.MainModule.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <v:ReportCommandsView Grid.Row="0"></v:ReportCommandsView>
     <v:LogItemListView Grid.Row="1" ></v:LogItemListView>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

First one ReportCommandsView works fine. However, I've got the problem when i put the the second usercontrol. It has a ListView, inside the listview, it has a gridview to present the items. Here is the xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.MainModule.Views.LogItemListView"
         x:Name="LogListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<ListView Name="LogItemListListView" FontSize="14"  Grid.Row="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=CurrentLogItem}"
              AlternationCount="2"
              BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="LogItemListGrid" 
              >

    <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Log Items View" >
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" Width="45"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Category"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Category.Description}" Width="120" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Institution"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Institution.Description}" Width="140" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Asset"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AssetCode}" Width="65" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Reader"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Reader}" Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Create Date"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CreateDate}" Width="170" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

I found that in the listview in the second usercontrol, the data is shown but it has no scrollbar. Because it shows all data. The data is under the bottom of the screen. I tried to set the max height, it can work, the scrollbar is came out. But it is not good for me. I need to handle when the screen size is changed. What can i do?

Comment: Where do you put `ReportView` control? Is it, or one of its parents, in `StackPanel` or `Canvas`?

Comment: I put it in a window, inside a tab control @dkozl

Comment: The whole structure is a main window, then there are some tab control, each tab control is combined of several user control.

Comment: Is it the only control on a tab? If not then what panel so you use to _combine several controls_ on a single tab?

Comment: yes. ReportView is the only control on that tab. But ReportView is consist of two user control. One of the control is the listview which named LogItemListListView. when the data is not much enough, it displays normally. However when the data is too much. It didnt appear a scrollbar to let me scroll down. It just keep display the data out of the bottom of the screen.